# Library with hash functions - JSP

Tags: security, jsp, hash

In php there is md5() to get a MD5 hash of string passed to it. So does JSP contains a predefined function like this ?

Or any premade library that i can use it easily, which contains all types of hash functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built in: [`javax.crypto`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html). Third party: [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Do the hashing in a Java class, such as a servlet or custom taglib.

Comment: thanku. But in javax.crypto.* which class provides MD5 hash function ? Or any example on how to hash a simple string using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated.

```
import java.security.*;


byte[] bom= str.getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = md.digest(bom);
```